# Am I doing callback in a proper way?

Tags: javascript

When I run the following code, I get the following error:

> ReferenceError: array is not defined

Why is it saying that array is undefined?

```js
var names = ["Lars", "Jan", "Peter", "Bo", "Frederik", "Anna"];

function myfilter(array, callback) {
  callback(array);
}

function turnaround(array) {
  var newArray = array.forEach(function(name) {
    if (name.indexOf("a") > -1) {
      return name;
    }
  });
}

console.log(myfilter(names, turnaround));
```

Comment: @Pvl That is a really bad suggestion, you should use `for...of` for Arrays, never `for...in`.

Comment: Where do you define your `names` array?

Comment: @Cristy You are right. I mean `for`. Bus seems like there is a filter and `filter` function is required

Comment: Cristy. I do it globally. var names = ["Lars", "Jan", "Peter","Bo", "Frederik","Anna"];

Comment: The code does not throw any errors, ReferenceError or otherwise. (The console.log statement logs undefined, but that is because `myfilter` has no return statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to add couple of return in the code. As you are trying to get the data back, for that you need to use return in functions.
Also its a good idea to use forEach when you arent storing any data to array. but `var newArray =` not gonna return anything as forEach doesnt return an array.
Hope this helps.

```js
var names = ["Lars", "Jan", "Peter", "Bo", "Frederik", "Anna"];

function myfilter(array, callback) {
  return callback(array);
}

function turnaround(array) {
  var newFilter = [];
  array.forEach(function(name) {
    if (name.indexOf("a") > -1) {
       newFilter.push(name);
    }
  });
  console.log(newFilter)
  return newFilter;
}

console.log(myfilter(names, turnaround));
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work and simplifies things a bit by using a filter, since you are looking to produce a new array.

```js
var names = ["Lars", "Jan", "Peter", "Bo", "Frederik", "Anna"];

function myfilter(array, callback) {
  return callback(array);
}

function turnaround(array) {
  return array.filter(name => name.indexOf("a") > -1);
}

console.log(myfilter(names, turnaround));
```

Comment: thanks Bryan. But for this exercise I just need to do it without filter!!!